# Excel VBA - VLookup with Varying File Names

Tags: excel, filenames, vlookup, vba

I am trying to perform a vlookup on a file that will not have a constant name. The file name is determined by the file names that are displayed in the two TextBoxes. I have started to set up the vLookup equation, but I am not sure what in it is going wrong when I run the macro. I get a type mismatch error from the vlookup line and the range value seems to come up empty. Is there some other way to reference the range that would work for this situation? Thanks for any help.

```
'Populating the textbox
Private Sub openDialog1()

Dim fd As Office.FileDialog
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fd
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Title = "Please select the report."
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Excel 2003", "*.xls"
  .Filters.Add "All Files", "*.*"
  If .Show = True Then
    FilePath1 = .SelectedItems(1)'The full File path
    ary = Split(.SelectedItems(1), "\")'Splitting the file name from the file path
    TextBox1.Value = ary(UBound(ary))'Displaying just the file name and extension

  End If
End With
End Sub
'The second textbox is filled the same way.


'VLookup using a cell in File 1 vs. the column in File 2
Private Sub Vlookup()

Windows(TextBox2.Value).Activate
myFileName2 = ActiveWorkbook.Name
mySheetName2 = ActiveSheet.Name
myRangeName2 = Range("B2:B2000")

Windows(TextBox1.Value).Activate
Columns("F:F").Select
Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Range("F2").Select

Range("F2").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2,[" & myFileName2 & "]" & mySheetName2 & "!" & myRangeName2 & ",1,0)" ' Having issues with the syntax here.

Range("F2").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("F2:F2000")
End sub
```

Comment: Start with `myRangeName2 = Range("B2:B2000").Address` to get the *B2:B2000* part out. If your worksheet name could conceivably contain a space then you will need to add wrapping ticks (aka apostrophes) like `='[Book1]Sheet 2'!$F$8`.

Comment: Ok that got my range to populate, but how would I get the ticks in there without commenting out everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start with `myRangeName2 = Range("B2:B2000").Address` to get the B2:B2000 part out. If your worksheet name could conceivably contain a space then you will need to add wrapping ticks (aka apostrophes) like `'[Book1]Sheet 2'!$B$2:$B$2000`. Example:

```
Range("F2:F2000").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2, '[" & myFileName2 & "]" & mySheetName2 & "'!" & myRangeName2 & ", 1, FALSE)"
```

The *ticks* start before the first square bracket and end just before the exclamation mark that separates the workbook/worksheet from the actual cell range.

You will note above that the formula can be applied in a relative *fill down* manner to all cells at once (replacing the separate `.FillDown` operation). *myRangeName2* needs to represent absolute cell addresses (e.g. $B$2:$B$2000) which is the default when used like `myRangeName2 = Range("B2:B2000").Address`. see [Address property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa174749(v=office.11).aspx) for more information.

**Addendum: .Address with external:=True**

While learning the proper string construction of a workbook/worksheet/cell range address is never a bad thing, the whole thing can be retrieved directly by adding the `, External:=True` parameter to the `.Address` retrieval.

```
myRangeName2 = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B2000").Address(RowAbsolute:=1, ColumnAbsolute:=1, external:=True)
Range("F2:F2000").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(E2, " & myRangeName2 & ", 1, FALSE)"
```

Comment: Afterthought: the ticks can go in whether they are actually needed or not. They do no harm unless they are absent when actually needed.

Comment: Thanks for helping with all that syntax. However, now I am getting an "application-defined or object defined error". Do have any thoughts on what would cause that in relation to the line.

Comment: @Tyler - Glad that worked out for you. If anyone else can see where I went wrong with my brick-by-brick approach, I would appreciate the error being pointed out so I can edit this 'answer' and make any necessary correction(s).